# Unable to chown recursively

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chown

I'm using this command:

```
chown root:www-data /var/www/example.com -R
```

but I get an error message that the directory is not listed.

What is wrong?

Comment: What  exact error message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `-R` option in front.

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/www/example.com
```

(I always use a dot instead of a colon between user and group, but the man pages says the colon should be used).

Comment: Er, I don't know why you think you can't use a colon: http://sprunge.us/aDJW

Comment: Dot was the *old way* and colon the new. Guess someone thought it'd be nice to be able to use dots in user-names/groups.

Comment: @Sukminder I guess that 'old way' identifies me. I am glad that dot is still allowed as it is difficult to change typing habits after using the command this way for close to 30 years

Comment: @Sukminder At one point Anthon said in his answer that colons were not allowed, which is not true. I wasn't trying to suggest that using a dot is "wrong" in some way, just that a colon is perfectly valid.

Comment: GNU tools allow options after arguments (which IMO is a bug) unless the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set (or `--` is used to mark the end of options). AFAIK, Ubuntu does not set that option in the default environment, so I doubt this be the issue. Anyway I agree one should put the options in front.

Answer (score 2):

The GNU coreutils version of `chown`, which is standard under Ubuntu, accept
options placed anywhere, (as long as `--` is not used). That is:

```
chown foo:bar some/location -R
chown -R foo:bar some/location
```

both work. This is because of how [`getopt_long()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long) works. In my book this is a bug – as it should either result in error, or be documented, which from
what I can find it is not.

```
chown foo:bar some/location -- -R
```

would look for directory named `-R`.

---

However if one set environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` the first example
would fail if there is no directory named `-R`, and would never recurse.

```
$ export POSIXLY_CORRECT=
$ chown -v :foo a/ -R
ownership of `a/' retained as foo:foo
chown: cannot access `-R': No such file or directory
```

IMHO: always try to conform to the POSIX way as one day you enter that command on another system where a POSIX is enforced, thus breaking.

Also note that the value of `POSIXLY_CORRECT` has no effect. This would not disable it:

```
export POSIXLY_CORRECT=0
export POSIXLY_CORRECT=no
export POSIXLY_CORRECT=false
export POSIXLY_CORRECT=...
```

One would need to `unset` it.

---

It could be your system is set up with either another `chown` tool or
`POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set.

Check by:

```
export | grep POSIX
chown --version
# etc.
```

---

As a side note, the use of dot, `.`, to separate group and user was obsoleted
as of [POSIX 2001](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chown-invocation.html#index-chown-1339) (`info coreutils 'chown invocation'`), but still supported for backwards compatibility, though
it is not recommended.